# What is Clipboard function in google chrome

Tags: function, google-chrome, clipboard

In google chrome there is function/constructor Clipboard what is used for? (it show up if you run `console.dir(window)`).

When I try to call that function

```
Clipboard();
```

it say that:

```
TypeError: Illegal constructor
```

the same if I try to create new instance

```
new Clipboard();
```

Comment: Same with `ClipboardEvent`, which is supposed to be part of Clipboard API — http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/clipops/clipops.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the spec](https://w3c.github.io/clipboard-apis/#clipboard-interface), `Clipboard` is supposed to be an interface implemented by `navigator.clipboard`. You can’t create a `Clipboard` by hand; you must use [`navigator.clipboard`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/clipboard).